# SQL Agent Job - exceptions handling in ETL package

Tags: sql, ssis, etl, sql-agent-job

I have a question on the SSIS below.

1. I have created an ETL package using SSIS.
2. I uses SQL Agent Job with the steps below.
   i. DB backup - Pre-ETL
   ii. Call the ETL package for execution.
   iii. DB backup - Post ETL

Due to connectivity issue, I would like to set the retry attempts in the Job step. However, as i know, the retry attempt will restart the step from the beginning instead of continue from the point it failed.

My question: Is it possible to set the SQL Agent job to continue from where the point it failed?

Example: 
- ETL is configured to load data into 100 tables. 
- When it load until 51th table, connection issue happen caused the ETL process to failed. 
- I want to set it to retry and continue to load the data at 51th table.

Any advice are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: You could consider creating a meta table to hold information about when each table was last loaded. Your SSIS package could look at this meta table to determine which tables still need to be loaded.
Did you consider such an approach?

Comment: There is no setting in the job, but in the ETL package, you could look into using `Checkpoints`.   I don't know if they work well with jobs or not.